# Kramnik vs Topalov 1996

Tags: endgame

Kramnik vs Topalov 1996 King Indian Bayonet Attack. After a ferocious Attack Kramnik did gain a pawn indeed on move 29, but failed to increase his advantage further and only drew the game. According to Houdini 6.02 Kramnik could have gained a second pawn indeed, but is the following position (black to move) really winning?

```
[FEN "4b3/8/4k1p1/4B3/r4P2/8/6PP/4R1K1 b - - 0 1"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
```

Comment: I don't see how White can get a pawn past f5 or h5 without reaching a drawn position.  Black can clamp the White Squares.  With rooks off it is a draw.  White needs to hope that Black will play ..g5?

Answer (score 2):

I will start by stating that all positions with the rooks traded and Black's pawn traded for *any* of Whites pawns is drawn. You can explore this for yourself in the [7-man tablebase](https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=8/8/8/1b2Bk2/5P2/8/5K1P/8_b_-_-_0_1).

We can use this information to understand that Blacks main defensive technique is to threaten the trade of rooks. This narrows the initial variation to **1...Bc6 2.Kf2** as only Kf2 properly deals with the threat of Ra2. Now after **2...Kf5** White again has an only move to avoid an obviously drawn situation: **3.Re2**.

After these more or less forced moves we reach the critical position.

```
    [FEN "8/8/2b3p1/4Bk2/r4P2/8/4RKPP/8 w - - 0 3"]
```

As for if this is a draw, Black already has the option to play **3...g5** forcing a trade of pawns. With all the pieces active and an opposite colour bishop dynamic I would put Black as a big favourite to draw.
Stockfish 13 prefers to delay **g6-g5** for a few more moves, starting with **3...Bb5** and gives an evaluation of 0.94 at depth 45.

With either third move from Black the position should be a draw as White cannot make progress due to the constant harassment from the rook and bishop, combined with the Black king standing firmly in front of the pawns.